# How to declare array value in Kotlin annotations?

Tags: java, arrays, annotations, arguments, kotlin

I have some problem with creating my own annotations in Kotlin. I have to create some annotations and in some of them i need to declare values with array type.
In java we can do this:

```
public @interface JoinTable {
...
    JoinColumn[] inverseJoinColumns() default {};
...
}
```

Where JoinColumn is also an annotation type.

I want to do something like that in Kotlin:

```
annotation class JoinTable(
    val name: String,
    val joinColumns: Array<JoinColumn>
)
```

I also tried to do this:

```
annotation class JoinTable(
    val name: String,
    val joinColumns: List<JoinColumn>
)
```

But my IDe says:

> Invalid type of annotation member

What should i do?

Thank you!

Comment: Very good explanation for your first post btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in java, the values for annotations must be available at compile time.
That means that `val joinColumns: List<JoinColumn>` is not possible if the `JoinColumn` is a usual class or data-class. 
If it's an enum class (`enum class JoinColumn`), than it's possible to use it.

See also the official kotlin documentation for allowed types https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

> Allowed parameter types are:
>
> - types that correspond to Java primitive types (Int, Long etc.);
> - strings;
> - classes (Foo::class);
> - enums;
> - other annotations;
> - arrays of the types listed above.
>
> Annotation parameters cannot have nullable types, because the JVM does
>   not support storing null as a value of an annotation attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I re-checked my annotations and found the mistake. I forgot mark JoinColumn as annotation

Answer (score 4):

So, it was my big fault. I didn't notice that JoinColumn in my realization isn't an annotation.

```
class JoinColumn()
```

Well, it fixed ^_^:

```
annotation class JoinColumn()
```